# How to integrate paypal payment gateway in android

Tags: android, paypal

Hai friends I am new in android app development. I want to integrate Paypal payment gateway in my new Android application. But I found that the Paypal android SDK was deprecated, is it true? I got two other methods Braintree direct and express checkout... Anybody, please tell me how to use the Braintree SDK for Paypal payment gateway integration

Comment: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/overview/android/v2

Comment: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android

Comment: thanks, @NileshRathod.  Can you please provide example code for the full implementation

Comment: I have already added link for example code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287630/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-android?noredirect=1#comment91523052_52287630